# Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I keep seeing the following error when I attempt to launch a lightbox:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /Images/designs/start-large.jpg
  [Break On This Error]     

throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

jquery.js (line 4679)
```

I am using the Colorbox Script. Here is my code:

***HTML***

```
<figure>
    <img src="/Images/designs/start.jpg" alt="Old Start Page"> 
    <dl>
        <dt class="strong">Purpose</dt>
            <dd>Original Website Opening</dd>
        <dt class="strong"><a href="/Images/designs/start-large.jpg" class="colorbox">Enlarge</a></dt>          
    </dl>
</figure>
```

***JS***

```
$(function() {
   $('.colorbox').colorbox();
});
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my code, when I click the link the lightbox opens but just shows an ajax spinner image. I have an inline element hidden on the page that opens correctly using the same exact code above (except the link is `href="#hidden-div"`).

What could be causing this error and how do I solve the problem?

Note: I am using jQuery 1.8.2 and Colorbox 1.3.20.1

***EDIT***

Here is additional code on my site:

```
$(function() {

    $('#reload').click(function() { 
location.reload(); //Reloads Page
 });

    $('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 5000 //Cycles Photos using jQuery Cycle Lite Plugin
});

//Original Code for Colorbox: $('.colorbox').colorbox(); 

$('.colorbox').colorbox({ //Current Colorbox Code
    inline: true
});

});
```

***EDIT 2***

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/7KP2Y/5/) Note: My code to call Colorbox is at the bottom of the JS Panel.

Comment: Don't use the minified jQuery for development.

Comment: @user1689607 - This page will be the production page and works great except for the colorbox. Also why not use the min version if it is what I will be using on the production page?

Comment: Because this: `h=h.slice(c.length),c.type=g,c.matches=d);if(!c)break}return b?h.length:h?bc.er.` ...is hard to debug.

Comment: Put what you're trying to debug in a jsfiddle, http and include the non-minified version of jquery instead so that it will be easier to debug,

Comment: check colorbox API to see what version of jQuery it is compatible with, and make sure you have most recent colorbox version

Comment: Put what you're trying to fix in a jsfiddle so that it will be easier to share with others, so that they can help you debug the issue. As well, include the non-minified version of jQuery so that it will make debugging a lot easier.

Comment: @charlietfl - According to the Colorbox page I am using the latest version and it is compatible with jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: The code you posted seems to work just fine - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/XbJyJ/1/). Possibly a link to a live scenario could he helpful.

Comment: @user1689607 - Posted Error from un-minified code.

Comment: @Lynda: Is that your 100% actual JS code, or have you changed it in any way? I understand the source of the error, but the code you posted wouldn't seem to be a cause.

Comment: @user1689607 - The colorbox code is identical, I posted the code that is handling other functions on the page as it appears on the page. I have a few other scripts that do more but those are across my entire site and do not have anything to do with colorbox and colorbox works properly with those scripts on other pages. I am curious though what that error means.

Comment: The `Sizzle` selector engine is throwing it. It appears that somehow the `href` of that element is being passed as a selector. The question doesn't seem to show any code that would do that. If you `.toString()` an `<a>` element, it gives you the `href`, so I would guess that somewhere the element is being converted to a string to be passed to `$` instead of passing the element itself. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FmS9L/

Comment: @user1689607 - Thanks for the information. I inserted the image into the page, then hide the image. I then changed the `href` from a direct link to the image to #image to call the `div` containing the image. That works without issue. I am perplexed.

Comment: I may be more help if you showed a little more code. At this point I couldn't tell where the issue would be. Any chance you could do a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: @user1689607 - Sorry for the delay, I added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/7KP2Y/5/) to my question. The error happens there with minimal code.

Comment: Sorry, just not sure. You may need to contact the plugin developer.

Comment: @user1689607 - Thanks for your help, I will contact the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this issue that involves adding extra code, not perfect but it does work.

Here is the code:

***HTML***

```
<a href="#lightbox1" class="colorbox">Show Lightbox</a>

<!-- Inserted before </body> tag -->
<div class="hide">
 <div id="lightbox1">
  <img src="path.jpg"> 
 </div>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$(function() {
  $(".colorbox").colorbox({
      inline:true
  });
});
```

***CSS***

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code to open an inline element in colorbox should be:

```
$('.colorbox').colorbox({ inline:true });
```

Hope this will help !!